# How to retrieve associated data in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, cascading-deletes

I have a problem. I have a domain that has child data. I can easily delete it by using Cascade delete but my teacher said that I must not cascade it. My plan is when the data has associations I will retrieve the associated and show it to the user. So far what I have is catching it by using try catch and I can display it on eclipse console. The display is:

`java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`EPS`.`EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYER`, CONSTRAINT`FK_EMPLOYEE_EMPLOYER_EMPLOYEE`FOREIGN KEY (`EMPLOYEE_ID`) REFERENCES`EMPLOYEE`(`EMPLOYEE_ID`))`

Since it throws an ajax error I did an alert that says `You cannot delete this record because it has associated record/s.`. I want to be more specific.

Then I don't know what to do next. I want to retrieve all associated data and display it. Please help.

Comment: "but my teacher said that I must not cascade it": for what reason? How is the relation between the "parent" and the "child"?

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite get your "solution".  You are talking about deleting an entity with all its child entities.  Retrieving the data and show to user has nothing to do with it.

First, I am not sure why your "teacher" tell you not to cascade.  This is a perfect valid and appropriate situation to make use of cascading.  Consider using delete-orphan and it will take the child entity delete for you.

If you really don't want to do cascading.  What you need to do is to do the cascading manually:  If you need to delete an entity, first get all its children, delete the children first, (may consider a flush here), and then delete the entity itself.  Not much relationship with Hibernate in fact.  That's a normal issue you will encounter when you works with DB.

Comment: I think he doesn't want to cascade but tell the user that there are dependencies.